# How do I use FRESetContextNativeData() in AIR native extensions?

Tags: c++, actionscript, air, native

I'm building an ANE.  In one of my calls into native code, there's an object that gets created, and I'd like to be able to keep that in memory to reference in a future call.

I thought I could could do this by creating a pointer to the object, and then passing that pointer to FRESetContextNativeData() as in the example below:

```
FREObject storeData(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    char* data = "testing...";
    FRESetContextNativeData( ctx, &data );
    return getFREString(data);
}

FREObject retrieveData(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    char* data;
    FREGetContextNativeData(ctx, (void**)&data);
    return getFREString(data);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work however.  At the end of retrieveData(), `data` points to a bunch of randomness.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm a bit of an idiot.  The mistake I made was putting `&` before `data` in my call to FRESetContextNativeData().  That one just needs a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer like FREGetContextNativeData().

The following code produces the results I was expecting:

```
FREObject storeData(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    char* data = "testing..."
    FRESetContextNativeData( ctx, (void*)data );
    return getFREString(data);
}

FREObject retrieveData(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    char *data;
    FREGetContextNativeData(ctx, (void**)&data);
    return getFREString(data);
}
```